# OGR2OGR Esri JSON to GeoJSON - Rings returning as null in geometry?

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert an Esri JSON file to a GeoJSON format using ogr2ogr. For some reason, in the objects returned, the geometry field is constantly null.

Here's the script I'm running:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.json`

Here's the input file: https://pastebin.com/RSx4L1vT

Here's the output file: https://pastebin.com/9tHnm2ZH

Here's the original source of the data which I have cleaned up: https://bexleycouncil.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/95a6e51df1734a859a502109a188790a/data?f=json

I'm fairly new to OGR/GDAL, and know it's something to do with the rings format, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: what if you use: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson ESRIJSON:input.json`

Comment: This JSON looks quite different than the ESRIJSON files which are used in GDAL driver tests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/autotest/ogr/data/esrijson. Looks like this data is meant to render a web page. Perhaps it is JSON from ESRI but not pure ESRIJSON that GDAL understands.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use Python 3, there are 2 ways to approach this issue:

1. Write a Python code (the longer way but you have better control to use precision, geometry type, and compliance checker using `geojson_rewind`.
2. Use the available python library: `arcgis2geojson` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/arcgis2geojson/)

Output: Here is a sample [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v3rykvcx93588i/output.geojson?dl=0) using the second approach:

Additional comments:

- I did not change your original SRS to latitude-longitude etc.for
  quick visualization.
- I am unsure if OGR has ESRIJSON driver to deal
  with your input data and it was easier to use the Python library.